# Why is javascript not making the value more than 1 using the +1

Tags: javascript

I can not make the output number bigger than one when I click a button I a using the `+1` operator.
I have search everywhere but just can not find a easy and good solution.

```html
<script>
  function more() {
    document.getElementById("more").innerHTML = +1; //plus one
  }
</script>

<p>You have </p>
<a href="#" id="more" class="list-group-item disabled">0 </a>
<img src="coin.png" width="2%" alt="coins">

<button onClick="more()">More!</button>//the button
```

Comment: The plus operator is a binary operator. It needs something on the left side and the right side, just like in regular math.

Comment: what sould I do I used += and it does not work too

Comment: Just because the OP is struggling with a basic programming problem does not mean this is a bad question.

Comment: I agree with the reopening, too. The OP is showing effort, including trying `+=` which it is understandable for someone to try.

Comment: While the question has been edited so it isn't unclear any more, the problem is  caused by a typo or similar problem that is not useful to future visitors so should not be reopened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you post a question try to post just what's needed.  Your php doesn't really add anything to the problem.  First get sum, then increase it by 1, then set innerHTML

```js
function more() {
  let sum = document.getElementById("more").innerHTML
  sum++
  document.getElementById("more").innerHTML = sum
}
```

```html
<p>You have </p><a href="#" id="more" class="list-group-item disabled">0 </a>

<button onClick="more()">More!</button>
```

Comment: Please tidy your snippets. I've done it for you this time.